# How do I get all symbol in python project using Eclipse+Pydev IDE

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How do I get all symbol in python project using Eclipse+Pydev IDE, just like project symbol list in Source Insight IDE.

3Q

Answer (score 0):

You can get the symbols in PyDev with Ctrl+Shift+T.

It'll open an editor which allows filtering by the name (accepting dotted paths).

I.e.: you can filter as:

my.*tok

Which can filter all tokens in any project starting with 'my' -- such as 'my_project' and any sub token which has a part as 'tok' in it.

When opened, the dialog has a description which explains it better.

Also, since you're at it, I really suggest reading:

- http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/navigating-through-your-code-when-in.html (it explains how to get to where you want in PyDev)
- http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/mastering-writing-code-on-pydev.html (gives other tips you really should know about)
- http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html (explains how to set things up).